# Navigating to .jar via sh

Tags: jenkins

Very new to jenkins so I apologize, getting the following while running my jenkins job:

> Now mvn clean install 
>   [Pipeline] 
>   echo Now Archiving... 
>   [Pipeline]
>   archiveArtifacts Error when executing success post condition:
>   hudson.AbortException: No artifacts found that match the file pattern
>   "**/target/*.jar". Configuration error?   at
>   hudson.tasks.ArtifactArchiver.perform(ArtifactArchiver.java:253)  at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep$Execution.run(CoreStep.java:80)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep$Execution.run(CoreStep.java:67)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:50)
>     at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:290)    at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
>     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> Archiving artifacts ‘**/target/*.jar’ doesn’t match anything: ‘**’
>   exists but not ‘**/target/*.jar’ [Pipeline] }

I'm trying to get it to simply build and find the .jar for now, then I will look into scp to my EC2 for a deployment stage.

Thanks

Git: https://github.com/BillyCharter87/Tech-O-Dex-API/blob/master/Jenkinsfile

Answer (score 0):

Have you confirmed if the files actually exists in your workspace after a build occurs??

```
def fileExists = fileExists '**/target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'

                if (fileExists) {
                    junit fileExists
                } else {
                    echo 'Sorry file does not exist have you skipped test ???'
                }
```

you can add this if you want in your code, checks if the file exists.

**P.S. trying mention the absolute PATH from the workspace and see if that works**

Hope it helps :)